# How to convert PDF to flipbook using Adobe Reader?

Tags: adobe

I want to convert my PDF files into flip book using Adobe Reader. How to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert your PDF files into a web based flip book using Adobe Reader but you can use one of the FlexPaper components to do so, we have both GPL and commercial alternatives

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/